# Linux Platform device "remove" method

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

question on standard practice when rmmod'ing a module with a platform device. When I remove my platform device it does not seem to call the .remove method defined in the `struct platform_driver`. In my `__exit` function, I'm calling `platform_device_unregister` and `platform_driver_unregister`, but from looking at source, neither of them *seem* to call the remove function. My current implementation calls the remove method manually in the `__exit` function, is this standard procedure for platform devices?

Comment: Your platform driver's remove method should get called automatically. It's hard to tell why that isn't happening without seeing your code, or at least a cut-down version of the code.

Comment: It's being called in the `platform_device_unregister` call. I did not look hard enough apparently.

Comment: Without minimal example it's hard to say. One of the possibilities might be an opened file or other ref counter that blocks `->remove()` to be called.